# css Change icon on hover + checked

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I'm working on a rating system with three hearts. I'm using font-awesome heart icons (full and empty ones). I want the second and third heart to change from empty to full when hovered and checked.

What I have so far is :

HTML

```
<section class="rating">

<p class="check" id="like">

          <!-- THIRD HEART -->
          <input type="radio" id="heart_3" name="like" value="3" />
          <label for="heart_3" class="heart-slider" data-hover="<i class='fa fa-heart' aria-hidden='true'></i>"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>

          <!-- SECOND HEART -->
          <input type="radio" id="heart_2" name="like" value="2" />
          <label for="heart_2" class="heart-slider" data-hover="<i class='fa fa-heart' aria-hidden='true'></i>"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>

          <!-- FIRST HEART -->
          <input type="radio" id="heart_1" name="like" value="1" checked="checked" />
          <label for="heart_1" class="heart-slider"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>

          </p>

</section>
```

CSS

```
.rating {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 85px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 45px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px white solid;
}


.check:not(:checked) > input {
  display: none;
}

/* - - - - - LIKE */
#like {
}
#like:not(:checked) > label {
  content: '';
  cursor:pointer;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;

}
#like:not(:checked) > label:hover,
#like:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
  content: attr(data-hover);

}
#like > input:checked + label:hover,
#like > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
#like > input:checked ~ label:hover,
#like > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
#like > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
 content: attr(data-hover);


}
#like > input:checked ~ label {
  content: attr(data-hover);

}
```

Nothing happens when hearts are hovered or clicked (=checked). What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible to swap the HTML of an element using CSS like this. You'll need to use something like jQuery to swap out the HTML instead.

Have a look at the [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector in jQuery and use the [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) function to swap the element when the are checked.

Something like (*not tested but an example*)...

```
$(".heart-1").is(":checked", function() {

    $(this).replaceWith("<i class='fa fa-heart heart-2' aria-hidden='true'></i>");

}), (function() {

    $(this).replaceWith("<i class='fa fa-heart heart-1' aria-hidden='true'></i>");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel James response is right, without some JS, you cannot make that changes when hovering.

Although I get inspired by you, I cannot did it quicker because of time, but here's my [rating system](http://codepen.io/RompePC/pen/LWmxKq), you can get guided with it:

```js
function click() {
  var input = $(this).prev();
  var max_value = parseInt(input.val());
  
  
  // We select the input of the clicked label to get actual checked value.
  input.click();
  // For each "rate":
  $.each($(".fa"), function() {
    // If we don't overpassed the maximum value (aka the clicked "rate" value) we activate the "rate".
    if (parseInt($(this).prev().val()) <= max_value) {
      $(this).removeClass("fa-star-o").addClass("fa-star");
    }
  });
}

function hover_in() {
  // This function is the same as "click()", but we don't check the associated input.
  var max_value = parseInt($(this).prev().val());
  
  
  $.each($(".fa"), function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).prev().val()) <= max_value) {
      $(this).removeClass("fa-star-o").addClass("fa-star");
    }
  });
}

function hover_out() {
  // We get the max rate checked (0 if there isn't anyone).
  var max_value = parseInt($("[name='rate']:checked").val()) || 0;
  
 
  $.each($(".fa"), function() {
    // If this "rate" is greater than the checked one, deselect it.
    if (parseInt($(this).prev().val()) > max_value) {
      $(this).removeClass("fa-star").addClass("fa-star-o");
    }
  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fa").click(click).hover(hover_in, hover_out);
})
```

```css
/* To hide the inputs. */
.rate {
  /* Box-model */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- A <input> and a <i> for each rate value. In this example they must been in this order. -->
<input class="rate" name="rate" type="radio" value="1">
<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<input class="rate" name="rate" type="radio" value="2">
<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<input class="rate" name="rate" type="radio" value="3">
<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<input class="rate" name="rate" type="radio" value="4">
<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<input class="rate" name="rate" type="radio" value="5">
<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```